# Lists changed in python functions

Tags: python, list

I'm having problems understanding what's going on here:

```
def foo(a, i): 
    i = i+1
    a = [ a[i] ] + a[1:] 
    print a
    return a

a = [ -1, 0, 6, 123 ] 
foo(a, a[1])
print a
print a[0] + a[1] + a[2]
# [0, 0, 6, 123]
# [-1, 0, 6, 123]
# 5

def foo2(a, i): 
    i = i+1
    a[0] = a[i]
    print a

x = [ -1, 0, 6, 123 ] 
foo2(x, x[1])
print x
print x[0] + x[1] + x[2]

# [0, 0, 6, 123]
# [0, 0, 6, 123]
# 6
```

Why is that in the first function/list gets changed by `foo` and the second list doesn't in `foo2`?

Comment: You seem to have it backwards: `a` *doesn't* get changed by `foo`, `x` *does* get changed by `foo2`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer simply, in foo you actually create a copy of the list by putting one element in a new list. The code you wrote for foo looks basically like this:

`[1] + [a[value] for value in range(1,len(a))]`

While in the second example, you just manipulate the list, which is a mutable object. if you do this instead, you wont change the list:

`def foo2(a, i):
    a = [value for value in a]
    i = i+1
    a[0] = a[i]
    print a`